# Logarithmic differentiation - when we can use it?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Assume I need to differentiate:
$$
f(x)=x^{\cos(x)}
$$
so, by using logarithmic differentiation, I get:
$$
f'(x)=x^{\cos(x)} \left( -\sin(x)\ln(x) + \frac{1}{x}\cos(x) \right)
$$
my questions are:

1. how can I determine from this process where the function $f$ is differentiable and where it is not?
2. Where is the function $f$ defined?

Hope someone will help me

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, check where $f'(x)$ exists and where it does not to find out where it is differentiable and where it is non-differentiable.

As for your $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ does not exist for $x \le 0$ , so $f(x)$ is not differentiable there.

For your second question, the process of differentiation is not important. You can check that from the function itself.

Comment: Is there something in the function itself that can prove that it is not differentiable when $x\leq 0 $ ? Thanks!

Comment: @georgia In general, we cannot make such a statement. For example, here your $f(x)=x^{\cos x}$ has both $x$ and $\cos x$ which are differentiable $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But $f(x)$ is not differentiable for $x \le 0$.

Comment: You're welcome..:-)

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$, the points where $f$ is non-zero, we can apply logarithmic differentiation. For your particular problem $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ and logarithmic differentiation is applicable for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: How can one say that logarithmic diff is legitimate when $f \neq 0 $ , ? Isn't $ln(f(x)) $ is defined only when $f(x)>0$? What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: Take $\ln (|f(x)|)$.

Comment: OK. Thanks! @@!